# Calcular valores em jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho três campos:

```
<input type="number" id="product_quantity" name="product_quantity" placeholder="Quantidade">

<input type="text" id="buying_price" name="buying_price" placeholder="Valor Total" value="" class="form-control autonumber" data-a-sign="R$ " data-a-sep="." data-a-dec=",">

<input class="form-control autonumber" data-a-sign="R$ " data-a-sep="." data-a-dec="," name="others_price" id="others_price" placeholder="Outras Despesas" type="text">
```

Preciso fazer o seguinte. Ao digitar o campo product_quantity, aparecer na div embaixo. return_qty_product - **se a caso preencher o campo others_price deverá somar ao outro valor e dividir pela quantidade**

Feito isto, preciso dividir o valor total, pela quantidade.

Exemplo: 500 unidades, o total da compra foi R$ 500,00
O resultado deverá ser 1. Na div results!

Como posso fazer isto em jQuery?

Edit:

Eu tentei fazer assim:

```
$("#product_quantity").keyup(function(){
    $(".product_quantity_return").html($("#product_quantity").val());
});                

$("#buying_price").keyup(function(){
    var price = $("#buying_price").val();
    var price_return = price.replace("R$ ", "");
    var price_return_b = price_return.replace(",", "");
    var calc = price_return_b/$("#product_quantity").val();
    //alert(calc)
    $(".buying_price_return").html(calc.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"}));
});
```

Mas o cálculo dá numero exato... Na calculadora eu fiz R$ 699,00 / 250 unidades - 2.79... mas arredondou para 2.80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade o resultado de 699/250 é 2.796. O `.toLocaleString` irá considerar apenas 2 casas decimais, mas se a terceira casa for maior ou igual a 5, é feito um arrendondamento para maior no valor da segunda casa decimal, logo 79 + 01 = 80.

Se você quer os exatos `2,79` como resultado, você precisa trabalhar em cima de string, pegando o valor antes e depois do ponto que separa as decimais.

Como você está usando máscara, deve fazer 2 replaces: um pra remover os pontos e outro para trocar a vírgula pelo ponto, isso para que o valor fique no formato que o JavaScript trabalha:

```
var price_return_b = price_return.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".");
```

Primeiro você deve converter o resultado em string com `.toFixed(3)` para pegar apenas 3 decimais depois do ponto. Isso até poderá arrendondar a 3ª casa decimal caso a 4ª seja maior ou igual a 5, mas não alterará a 2ª casa, que é o que interessa:

```
var calc = (price_return_b/$("#product_quantity").val()).toFixed(3);
```

Em seguida pode usar o método `.substr` para pegar o valor antes e depois do ponto e depois concatenar:

```
calc = calc.substr(0, calc.indexOf(".")) + calc.substr(calc.indexOf("."),3);
```

Depois é preciso converter a string em float:

```
calc = parseFloat(calc);
```

Na questão do evento `keyup`, é melhor usar o evento `input` que irá atualizar o valor até quando você clicar nas setas com campo tipo *number*. Porém, a máscara já usa esse evento no campo, então você pode usar os dois eventos ao mesmo tempo nos 3 campos:

```
$(""#buying_price, #product_quantity, #others_price"").on("keyup input", function(){...
```

E você já pode remover esse código:

```
$("#product_quantity").keyup(function(){
    $(".product_quantity_return").html($("#product_quantity").val());
});
```

A função ficará assim:

```
$("#buying_price, #product_quantity, #others_price").on("keyup input", function(){

   $(".product_quantity_return").html($("#product_quantity").val());

    var others = $("#others_price").val();
    var others_return = others.replace("R$ ", "");
    var others_return_b = others_return.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".") || 0;

    var price = $("#buying_price").val();
    var price_return = price.replace("R$ ", "");
    var price_return_b = price_return.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".") || 0;
    var calc = ((parseFloat(price_return_b)+parseFloat(others_return_b))/$("#product_quantity").val()).toFixed(3);
    calc = calc.substr(0, calc.indexOf(".")) + calc.substr(calc.indexOf("."),3);
    calc = parseFloat(calc);
    //alert(calc)
    $(".buying_price_return").html(calc.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"}));
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$("#buying_price, #others_price").maskMoney({
    prefix: "R$ ",
    decimal: ",",
    thousands: "."
});
            
$("#buying_price, #product_quantity, #others_price").on("keyup input", function(){

   $(".product_quantity_return").html($("#product_quantity").val());

    var others = $("#others_price").val();
    var others_return = others.replace("R$ ", "");
    var others_return_b = others_return.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".") || 0;

    var price = $("#buying_price").val();
    var price_return = price.replace("R$ ", "");
    var price_return_b = price_return.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".") || 0;
    var calc = ((parseFloat(price_return_b)+parseFloat(others_return_b))/$("#product_quantity").val()).toFixed(3);
    calc = calc.substr(0, calc.indexOf(".")) + calc.substr(calc.indexOf("."),3);
    calc = parseFloat(calc);
    //alert(calc)
    $(".buying_price_return").html(calc.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"}));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/master/dist/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="product_quantity" name="product_quantity" placeholder="Quantidade">
<input type="text" id="buying_price" name="buying_price" placeholder="Valor Total" value="" class="form-control autonumber" data-a-sign="R$ " data-a-sep="." data-a-dec=",">
<input class="form-control autonumber" data-a-sign="R$ " data-a-sep="." data-a-dec="," name="others_price" id="others_price" placeholder="Outras Despesas" type="text">
<br>
<div class="buying_price_return"></div>
```

Comment: Então é isso mesmo, porém, se eu adicionar a quantidade e o valor, dá certo, se eu alterar a quantidade, não dá certo... o que pode ser?

Comment: Ainda tem falha... vamos suporte que eu coloque no campo quantidade 10, e no campo valor total 10,00, o retorno deveria ser 1,00. até ai funciona, se eu trocar a quantidade pra 20, o preço médio retorna 50,00.

Comment: Fiz o mesmo teste aqui no executar, e dá certo, mas quando eu volto o campo anterior, ele refaz o calculo

Comment: Aí dá a diferença

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lpssqw

Comment: O problema está em eu alterar a quantidade... ele modifica também o resultado, oque deveria mesmo, mas me parece que ele multiplica..

Comment: Deve ser porque o campo do valor tem uma máscara... vou dar uma olhada aqui

Comment: O problema é o seguinte... eu tenho dois campos, e um adicional. Quando eu preencho a quantidade, ele puxa a quantidade no retorno, até ai, ok.. porém, o calculo só funciona se eu alterar por segundo a quantidade, incluir o valor primeiro e por segundo a quantidade

Comment: Então, deve ser a máscara que tá subvertendo isso... vc tá usando máscara no campo do valor, não tá?

Comment: estou sim, vou tirar a masc pra ver

Comment: o problema são as casas decimais... eu fiz o código sem levar em consideração isso, vou arrumar

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86525/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-sam).